# How to edit content in fckeditor

Tags: php, html, database, forms, fckeditor

Here is my code. I want to edit the content or value in fckeditor. This code is running insert and select queries but cannot update. Please help me to reslolve it.

below it is receive an id from database to select the record

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['editncontent'])) {
        $editnews  = new DBConnection();
        $condition = "WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST['editncontent']."'";
        $selnews   = $editnews->SelectRecord(array("*"),"pages","$condition");

        while ($getnews = mysql_fetch_array($selnews)){ ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <?php
                $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor1');
                $oFCKeditor->BasePath = 'fckeditor/';
                $oFCKeditor->Width = 740;
                $oFCKeditor->Height = 600;
                $oFCKeditor->Value  = $getnews['content'];
                echo $oFCKeditor->Create();
            ?>
            </form>
<?php } } ?>

// Now it takes the parameter and going to update it         
// Update query

<?php  
    if (isset($_REQUEST['content'])) {
        $content = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['FCKeditor1']));

        $obj        = new DBConnection();
        $arr_field  = array("content");
        $arr_values = array("$content");
        $condition  = "WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST['editncontent']."'";
        $update     = $obj->UpdateRecord(
            "pages",$arr_field,$arr_values,"$condition"
        ) or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location:showpages.php");
    }
    ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: i can't edit the value which is in fckeditor. It will show the value in fckeditor by using select query but can't update it. This is the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clean your code to make it more readable and try to avoid that horizontal scrollbar.  Thank you.